# Concurrent VPN connections in the VPN Router

Tags: router, vpn, connection

I am planning to procure a Cisco RV042 VPN Router, [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/rv042-dual-wan-vpn-router/data_sheet_c78-501225.html) are the specifications for the same. How to figure out the number of concurrent VPN connections possible by looking at the specifications?

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about remote dial in VPN as in Cisco VPN client then its 50 depending on licensing... QuickVPN 50 QuickVPN tunnels for remote client access